# Python extracting a subset from tuple that is sql result

Tags: python, tuples, subset

my code executes a query:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select studentId from students order by avgGrade desc")
ids = cursor.fetchall()
```

I'm running on all students so I can figure how many are there by

```
numberOfStudents = len(ids)
```

then I wish to get the objects only of the top 10, 
How can I change this statement to work on 10 instead of all ids?

```
Students.objects.filter(studentid__in=[p[0] for p in ids])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list slicing to get top 10 elements from the ids list.

```
Students.objects.filter(studentid__in=[p[0] for p in ids[:10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the two tasks in two sql queries

```
select count(studentId) as number_of_students from students
```

and

```
select studentId from students order by avgGrade desc limit 10
```

This way you would avoid downloading all the studentid's in case that it is a very long list.

Comment: the sql I gave is just an example. mine is very complex and heavy running it twice will take too much time.